# How to display area borders in embedded map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When i am searching for some country area in maps on standard web UI it shows me the area borders.

I would like to mark this areas dynamically in embedded map on my website, but i dont know how exactly i have to formulate search query to find if there is some way to achieve this.
I was not found anything about this in reference.

does google offer some API for this in last maps js API?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Polygon-Overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polygon) or a [KML-Layer](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#KmlLayer)  which defines the borders.

Comment: I dont want to do it via custom layers.
I thought theres way how to let it render google when he already got it.